# Error Handling When Saving a CKRecord

Tags: ios, cloudkit, nserror

I am looking for an example of proper error handling when saving a `CKRecord`. According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecord_class/index.html) I should "Use the information in the error object to determine whether a problem has a workaround."

I understand that the error object has a `userInfo` dictionary, but how do I figure out what the keys are for the dictionary and how to handle the errors?

The following example illustrates how I'm currently saving a `CKRecord`:

```
    CKRecord *record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"MyRecordType"];
[record setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:99] forKey:@"myInt"];

[db saveRecord:record completionHandler:^(CKRecord *savedPlace, NSError *error) {
    // handle errors here
    if (savedPlace) {
        NSLog(@"save successful");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"save unsuccessful");
    }
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }

}];
```

How can I improve this code to provide work arounds for potential saving issues?

Comment: 1) See the docs for `CKErrorCode` for possible values of the `NSError code` property. The `userInfo` on the error is only used for a couple of those codes. 2) Your `if` check is wrong. It's only successful if `error == nil` as stated in the docs for `CKDatabase saveRecord:completionHandler:`.

Answer (score 2):

In my library [EVCloudKitDao](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao) I have a separate method that will return a error type based on the error code. Depending on that type you can decide what to do. Here is that method:

```
public enum HandleCloudKitErrorAs {
    case Success,
    Retry(afterSeconds:Double),
    RecoverableError,
    Fail
}

public static func handleCloudKitErrorAs(error:NSError?, retryAttempt:Double = 1) -> HandleCloudKitErrorAs {
    if error == nil {
        return .Success
    }
    let errorCode:CKErrorCode = CKErrorCode(rawValue: error!.code)!
    switch errorCode {
    case .NetworkUnavailable, .NetworkFailure, .ServiceUnavailable, .RequestRateLimited, .ZoneBusy, .ResultsTruncated:
        // Use an exponential retry delay which maxes out at half an hour.
        var seconds = Double(pow(2, Double(retryAttempt)))
        if seconds > 1800 {
            seconds = 1800
        }
        // Or if there is a retry delay specified in the error, then use that.
        if let userInfo = error?.userInfo {
            if let retry = userInfo[CKErrorRetryAfterKey] as? NSNumber {
                seconds = Double(retry)
            }
        }
        NSLog("Debug: Should retry in \(seconds) seconds. \(error)")
        return .Retry(afterSeconds: seconds)
    case .UnknownItem, .InvalidArguments, .IncompatibleVersion, .BadContainer, .MissingEntitlement, .PermissionFailure, .BadDatabase, .AssetFileNotFound, .OperationCancelled, .NotAuthenticated, .AssetFileModified, .BatchRequestFailed, .ZoneNotFound, .UserDeletedZone, .InternalError, .ServerRejectedRequest, .ConstraintViolation:
        NSLog("Error: \(error)")
        return .Fail;
    case .QuotaExceeded, .LimitExceeded:
        NSLog("Warning: \(error)")
        return .Fail;
    case .ChangeTokenExpired,  .ServerRecordChanged:
        NSLog("Info: \(error)")
        return .RecoverableError
    default:
        NSLog("Error: \(error)") //New error introduced in iOS...?
        return .Fail;
    }
}
```

Inside the callback of a CloudKit method you can then use this function like this:

```
func loadContacts(retryCount:Double = 1) {        
    // Look who of our contact is also using this app.
    EVCloudKitDao.publicDB.allContactsUserInfo({ users in
            EVLog("AllContactUserInfo count = \(users.count)");
            Async.main{
                self.contacts = users
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }, errorHandler: { error in
            switch EVCloudKitDao.handleCloudKitErrorAs(error, retryAttempt: retryCount) {
            case .Retry(let timeToWait):
                Async.background(after: timeToWait) {
                    self.loadContacts(retryCount + 1)
                }
            case .Fail:
                Helper.showError("Something went wrong: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            default: // For here there is no need to handle the .Success, .Fail and .RecoverableError
                break
            }
    })
}
```

In my the case above I use a separate error callback handler. You can also call it directly form within a CloudKit method callback. Just first check if there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation in which I handle the common error of `CKErrorNetworkFailure` by retrying to save after the recommended retry after time interval which is stored in the `userInfo` dictionary.

```
-(void)saveRecord:(CKRecord*)record toDatabase:(CKDatabase*)database{
[database saveRecord:record completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
    if (error==nil) {
        NSLog(@"The save was successful");
        //Do something
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error saving with localizedDescription: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"CKErrorCode = %lu", [error code]);

        if ([error code]==CKErrorNetworkFailure) {
            double retryAfterValue = [[error.userInfo valueForKey:CKErrorRetryAfterKey] doubleValue];
            NSLog(@"Error code network unavailable retrying after %f", retryAfterValue);
            NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:retryAfterValue target:self selector:@selector(testOutCloudKit) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
            [timer fire];
        }
    }
}];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, I handle my CloudKit errors this way:

```
privateDB.perform(myQuery, inZoneWith: nil)  {records, error in
    if error != nil {
        print (error?.localizedDescription)
        if error?._code == CKError.notAuthenticated.rawValue {
            // Solve problems here...
        }
```

Note that the CKError.notAuthenticated is selected from the list presented by code completion after writing CKError.

Hope this helps!